# Adding an element of an array with respective element of other arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have multiple array, number can be arbitrary. but the size of all array is same. How do i add each element of with respective element of all the arrays and maybe save it in another array

```
A1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6]

A2 = [1 2 3 4 5 6]

.

.

.

.

final = [1+1+1+...  2+2+2+.... 3+3+3+3.... 4+4+4.... 5+5+5+5...   6+6+6+6...]
```

Comment: What program language?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add, matlab

Comment: Can you gives an example? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you show some example: example of input array and example of array you want to achieve?

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam, check the new edit pls

Comment: `final = A1+A2+...+AN` ?

Comment: i do not know how many A's are there, thats the problem

Comment: Then you should probably not generate all of those different variables. If you put them all in one array, `A(n,:)`, you would know how many there were. Plus you would be able to sum them with one command.

Comment: I could give you a solution using `eval`. The problem is: I would have to downvote my own answer because it encourages using `eval`. Since I can't vote on my own answer that means I can't answer this question either. Sorry.

Comment: How do you generate `A1`, `A2`, etc?

Comment: @beaker with a for loop, they are stored in a structure

Comment: I don't know why i am getting down voted, this was a genuine question

Comment: In that case it should be easy to add them to an array as they are generated, as I suggested. Then the answer to your question becomes `final = sum(A)`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because creating variable names like this rather than using arrays, for which MATLAB is optimized, only complicates your code, makes it slower, less readable and less maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have this structure (as you write in the comments):

```
main = struct('err',{1:6,5:10,1:6,1:6},'seg_err',{1:6,5:10,1:6,5:10});
```

you can convert it to matrix:

```
m = vertcat(main.seg_err);;
```

And than take the sum in a simple command:

```
final = sum(m)
```

which results:

```
final =

     12    16    20    24    28    32
```

and thanks to @beaker :)

Comment: This assumes there is nothing else in the struct but the `A` arrays, correct?

Comment: Yes, but could be easily manipulated if there is anything else. And any manipulation would be more correct then involving `eval`.

Comment: I agree, I'm just trying to give the OP the information necessary to write correct code for their case.

Comment: Hey, I have other attributes other than the ones i need to add, how do i manipulate

Comment: What is in common to all the attributes you want to add? How do you find them in structure? Can you give an example to your real structure?

Comment: like say my struct name is 'main' and the attribute name is 'err', i want to add, i want to add all 'seg err'. 'main(1).seg_err','main(2).seg_err', 'main(3).seg_err'.....

Comment: @user5603723 `A = vertcat(main.seg_err);`

Comment: @beaker, that just concatenates  the arrays, i wanted to the elements of respective position

Comment: @EBH, your method was shown to add all attributes of same structure, what i am looking for is add attributes of different structure

Comment: You write _"I want to add all 'seg err'. 'main(1).seg_err','main(2).seg_err', 'main(3).seg_err'..."_ where is the different structure?

Comment: Yeah sorry, got confused. Too many data structures. My apologies

Comment: @user5603723 It would be nice if you added the information about your structure and what fields you want to extract from it to your original question so that there's some context for the answer.

Comment: I just tested the method randomly, i will implement it and will update the main post, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

As your arrays are all the same length you can just add the arrays forming a new array.

```
final = A1+A2
```

This function searches in your workspace looking for all variables containing capital 'A'. The for loop adds all found variables. If there are other variables containing 'A', other restrictions has to be made.

```
variables = who %# all variable names from workspace
index = strmatch('A',variables) %# indices matching "A"
newarray = 0 

for j = 1:numel(index)
    tmp =  eval(char(variables(index(j)))); %# store variable in tmp 
    newarray = newarray + tmp; %# sum 
end
```

Comment: How are your initial arrays stored? Do you import them from outside matlab or are they already in workspace? Do they have similar names?

Comment: they are in the work place, and yes they have similar names.

Comment: I think Scotty's answer is more elegant in this case. So I give you a point.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an unknown number of A's, you can try something like this:

```
final = 0
i = 1
while exist(['A' num2str(i)]) == 1 % ['A' num2str(i)] constructs the variable name, eval calls it
    final = final + eval(['A' num2str(i)]);
    i = i + 1;
end
```

This should work as long as the variables are stored in the workspace, are of the same length and are named A1, A2, A3, ... A9, A10, ...

Comment: PROTIP: if you need to use eval, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Ander Biguri: honestly: _proproprotip_: I know the downsides of eval, but for a calculation this simple and with such sparse information: simple is king!

Comment: Hm k, looks like my answer wasn't accepted even though it was the first one solving the actual problem... :/

Comment: You solved it in different ways. I guess OP liked the other solution better, or just accepted a random one. Accepting the first answer is common if the answers are identical. In this case they are far from it. +1 from me though, I think it's a nice solution :)

Comment: both works. I just needed time to test out both. apparently i can't take 2 answers

Comment: Oh ok, that was not meant that you need to change the accepted answer! But thanks alot! The vote is appreciated! And thanks Stewie as well!

Comment: If, for any reason, the no. of the `A` jump (i.e. from `i` to `i+2`), than this solution won't work.

Comment: That's imho one thing you can avoid easily by adding an exception. Considering the question asked this seems like the shortest solution to me. Using structs imho makes this problem more complicated than it is and needs adapting of the initial situation...